# show bootstrap modal when onclick is trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

can someone help me or guide me how to accomplish the following.

this is my code

```
<span class="blink" >
    <?php 
        if ($item ['in_stock'] < 20)
            echo "<p onclick='stock()'>! Alerta</p>";
        else 
            echo "<p style='display:none;'>" .'WER ALL CLEAR' ."</p>";  
    ?>
    <?php echo form_hidden('location', $item['item_location']); ?>
</span>
```

i will like to when i onclick it triggers the bootstrap modal,  i tried by using the given manual script but im not lucky with it.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myBtn").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

now i used the above example to get it display, how can i get this done, i know i have to change the ids butjust cant get it i changed the script with

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("blink").click(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    });
</script>
```

but it kept saying $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: shouldn't it be $(".blink").rather than $("blink").??

Answer (score 0):

One option, on the element you are clicking on to open the modal, you could add these attributes (you need to update the target attribute with your id).

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
```